# forced inserted ^Z in coc

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-coc, popup-menu

I'm using the plugin `coc` for autocompletion.

My problem is that when coc opens the pop up menu with the completion items and I continue typing then a `^Z` character is inserted in the buffer as shown in the following screenshots:

Before typing:
[image: before typing]

After typing:
[image: after typing ignore suggestion box]

Where is this behavior coming from and how can I avoid that?

Comment: Hi, did you try using `set completeopt+=noinsert` in your .vimrc? might work, but I'm not 100% sure since I don't have `coc` installed :)

Comment: @NordineLotfi Thanks for your comment, Actually I issued to COC Team Github on question and They are fixed about this bug.